# Кривое отоброжение на мобильных устройствах

Tags: html, css, mobile, float

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что на телефоне очень криво отображается, весь экран не во всю отоброжается. вот ссылка http://catalogue.woodstock.org.ua/collection.html . На айфоне заметно. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Думается мне, что проблема в body { min-width: 480px; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед `<html>` добавьте `<!DOCTYPE html>`
И вьюпорт замените вот на этот `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: поставил,и все равно тоже самое. Я просто не понимаю почему появляется скрол, если я везде ставлю witdh: 100%;

Comment: CNTRL+F5 нажмите после замены

Comment: @Ncorvenius нужно не witdh: 100% ставить, а width: 100%

Comment: Я чуть ошибся, именно это стоит. И все равно такая проблема: http://prntscr.com/gdm77c Кэш я отключил.

Comment: @Ncorvenius попробуйте этот код бутстраповский добавить в head `<link rel="stylesheet" ref="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: @Ncorvenius и уберите из body в css вот эту строчку `min-width: 480px; `

Comment: @Ncorvenius Напишу позже, мне нужно отключится

Comment: спасибо большое, все нормально, то у меня почему-то на локалке было криво